# How to use custom Dynamic inside Manipulate

Tags: dynamic, manipulate

I was wondering if it is possible to use a custom `Dynamic[var, function]` inside a `Manipulate`. The reason for the need is this:

Suppose you have a time consuming computation like

```
timeConsuming[x_] := (Pause[1]; x)
```

and you want to use it in a `Manipulate`. Writing

```
DynamicModule[{y},
 Manipulate[
  y = timeConsuming[x]; {x, y, other},
  {x, 0, 1},
  {other, 0, 1}]
 ]
```

entails the following issue: you have to wait for `timeConsuming` to be computed even when you change `other` and leave `x` unmodified.
A (simple) solution is to code the dynamic by hand:

```
DynamicModule[{x = 0, y = timeConsuming[0], other = 0},
 Panel@Column[{
    Grid[{
      {"x", Slider[Dynamic[x, (x = #; y = timeConsuming[x]) &], {0, 1}]},
      {"other", Slider[Dynamic[other], {0, 1}]}
      }],
    Dynamic@{x, y, other}
    }]
 ]
```

This is feasible, but as a drawback makes you renounce all other `Module`'s conveniences.

I tried coding something like

```
Module[(* result *), {x, 0, 1, some-suitable-function}]
```

but had no success in the attempt.
A (clean) use of `Manipulate` would be much appreciated.

Just to summarize, the question is: How can I make some statements be executed only when some specified controls are touched?

Comment: Welcome to _Mathematica_ Stack Exchange! Nice and well written first question :)

Comment: Thank you! I hope I will be helpful to somebody someday.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
timeConsuming[x_] := (Pause[1]; x);
DynamicModule[{y},
 Manipulate[y = timeConsuming[x]; {Dynamic@x, y, Dynamic@other},
  {x, 0, 1}, {other, 0, 1},
  SynchronousUpdating -> False]
 ]
```

`SynchronousUpdating -> False` keeps the front end from being blocked while `timeConsuming` is computing, and `Dynamic` lets different segments be updated.  So `x` and `other` both update when the sliders are moved, and `y` is updated one second after `x` is.

Comment: Yes, this is _exactly_ what I was after! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

- It is straightforward to use `Dynamic[var]` in a `Manipulate` :

Simply insert `Dynamic` in the code !
This gives :

```
timeConsuming[x_] := (Pause[1]; x)

DynamicModule[{y},
Manipulate[
 y = timeConsuming[x]; {x, y, Dynamic[other]},
 {x, 0, 1},
 {other, 0, 1}]
 ]
```

You will see that this has exactly the effect you want : The slider `other` will respond immediatly.

This is documented in the "Advanced Manipulate Tutorial" (chapter "Using Dynamic inside Manipulate")

- But if you want something like to use a `Dynamic[var,function]` in a `Manipulate` , I have no solution (presummatly it is useful).

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that chapter out to me. For some reason i missed it. Anyway, I have never had the necessity to implement sophisticated dynamic construct, so my knowledge is very limited in this field.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a different solution, using `Dynamic[var, function]`:

```
customControl[Dynamic[x_], Dynamic[y_], b_, e_] :=
 Slider[Dynamic[x, (x = #; y = timeConsuming[x]) &], {b, e}]
Manipulate[
 {x, y, other},
 {{x, 0}, customControl[#1, Dynamic[y], 0, 1] &},
 {{y, timeConsuming[0]}, ControlType -> None},
 {other, 0, 1},
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

although it is still not completely clear to me why the wrapper `Dynamic` is required around `y`.
As far as I can tell, its only purpose is to prevent `y` from being evaluated and make it retain its symbolic nature.
Therefore, the same could be achieved by

```
customControl[Dynamic[x_], Hold[y_], b_, e_] :=
 Slider[Dynamic[x, (x = #; y = timeConsuming[x]) &], {b, e}]
Manipulate[
 {x, y, other},
 {{x, 0}, customControl[#1, Hold[y], 0, 1] &},
 {{y, timeConsuming[0]}, ControlType -> None},
 {other, 0, 1},
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Comment: This has a behavior similar to andre's: the update of `x` and `y` in the output and the `x` control have to wait until `timeConsuming` finishes.  In mine both `x` and `other` respond immediately to their controls; only `y` has to wait.  Any of them might be a desired solution to a given problem, but there is a difference.

Comment: You're right about `Dynamic` vs. `Hold`.  The main requirement is that the first argument has to match `Dynamic[var]`, where `var` is the `Manipulate` variable, because that is what `Manipulate` will pass to your function.  You could for instance start your definition `customControl[_[x_], _[y_], b_, e_] := ..`

Comment: I just wonder why `Manipulate` does not pass the variable itself. It looks more versatile to me, because there is no "functional" way (at least that I know) to extract the variable from `Dynamic[var]` without recurring to an external definition and pattern matching, whereas one could prevent the evaluation of a naked passed variable with `Unevaluated` and `HoldFirst`.

Comment: Because the standard controls are defined like this: `Slider[Dynamic[x],..]` etc.  And because `x` must be held, not evaluated, although there are other ways to do this.