# Wrap custom control inside Manipulate or DynamicModule

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, gui-construction

[Apologies if this is a duplicate: I have looked at quite a few related questions but have not seen this issue dealt with]

I have built a custom control, using the following method:

> ```
> customControl[Dynamic[x_]] := True;
> Manipulate[{x, 1, other}, 
>      {{x, 0}, customControl[#1] &}, 
>      {{y, 0}, ControlType -> None}, 
>      {other, 0, 1}])]
> ```

and now all I need to do is wrap the definition of `customControl` inside `DynamicModule`.

I thought I would know how to do this, from questions such as [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5335/4811) and answers such as [Federico's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21754/4811).  But I'm meeting a problem with internalising a custom control to a `DynamicModule` and/or `Manipulate`.  The example below is the simplest one I could come up with that illustrates the problem, which appears to be one of pattern-matching rather than the definition of my `customControl`.  This is why the controls I'm defining don't actually do anything: if I can get the pattern to match, then I think I'm in business.  So consider the following, which yields the same output as my example above:

> ```
> Clear[customControl] 
> DynamicModule[{customControl}, 
>   (customControl[Dynamic[x_], _] := True;
>    Manipulate[{x, 1, other},
>      {{x, 0}, customControl[#1, y] &}, 
>      {{y, 0}, ControlType -> None}, {other, 0, 1}])]
> ```
>
> [image: image of output of this code]

So far so good: `customControl` is called and returns `True` as expected.  A small change--which you might think is inconsequential, because it involves dropping an argument to `customControl` which is never used, yields a different result:

> ```
> Clear[customControl] 
> DynamicModule[{customControl}, 
>   (customControl[Dynamic[x_]] := True;
>    Manipulate[{x, 1, other},
>      {{x, 0}, customControl[#1] &}, 
>      {{y, 0}, ControlType -> None}, {other, 0, 1}])]
> ```
>
> [image: image of output of above code]

So it might seem that `x` is not considered as a `Dynamic` object when `customControl` is called on it unless it is somehow linked to another `Dynamic` object through a common invocation, even if that invocation doesn't actually do anything.  My first example does not work if the 2nd argument to `customControl` is a constant such as 0; it needs to be y. [Or x?  I didn't try that...]

[The reason I'm asking this specific question: the code is destined for a CDF interface.  `SaveDefinitions -> True` is of no help or hope in my application; I need to localise everything within `DynamicModule`s.  It works fine with `Module` but of course that's deprecated (and in Mma10 this is very visible with red highlighting)]

Now I've written all that, I do have a dim memory of a similar question involving dynamic variables and needing to have more than one around...but I haven't found it.

Comment: I tried using x instead of y as a dummy argument.  It worked just fine.

Comment: does this work: `{{x,0},Dynamic@customControl[#] &}` ?

Comment: ... or `{{x, 0}, (y; customControl[#]) &}`  or `{{x, 0}, (other; customControl[#]) &}` ?

Comment: @kguler Both work.  Odd thing is, I met this problem in a much more complex situation where many variables were being evaluated; but perhaps it was precisely because I tried to develop these techniques in isolation from the concrete problem I had that I fell into this trap.

Comment: So do these then: `Dynamic[Control[{{x, 0}, customControl[#]&}]]` and `{{x, 0}, customControl[Dynamic[x]] &}`?

Comment: yep. I'd been thinking of using `Control` anyway...

Comment: fairflow, so ... would you like to self-answer your question based on the suggestions in the comments above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18779/discussion-between-fairflow-and-kguler).

Comment: @kguler: Perhaps an answer here would help me with [a question I have](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78398/37).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius, just saw your comment. Meanwhile, Michael's answer to your linked question is the best way to get custom controls to behave like regular controls .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this has gone unanswered for so long and I can add one clarification to the comments under the question, I'll fill out an answer.

In the comments, it has been observed that the following work (with the appropriate definition of `customControl`):

```
{{x, 0}, customControl[#1, y] &}
{{x, 0}, customControl[Dynamic[x]] &}
{{x, 0}, Dynamic@customControl[#1] &}
```

And the following does not:

```
{{x, 0}, customControl[#1] &}
```

*Why is that?*

`Manipulate` does many things automatically. When an expression contains a variable declared in the `Manipulate`, it makes sure that the expression is wrapped in `Dynamic`.  This happens anyway with the body of the `Manipulate`, but it also happens for controls. (User expressions other than controls that are formatted in the control area need to be wrapped in `Dynamic` by the programmer.)  The first two specifications above that work explicitly contain `Manipulate` variables, `x` or `y`, and so they get wrapped in `Dynamic`.  The third example is explicitly wrapped in `Dynamic` by the programmer.

The one that does not work does not contain a `Manipulate` variable and does not wrapped in `Dynamic`.  Consequently, the front end does not update `` $CellContext`customControl$$ `` with its `DynamicModule` value.  Therefore it is not evaluated.

One can discover evidence of this analysis by examining
`` Typeset`specs$$ ``
in the cell expression (menu command Cell > Show Expression).
The following is from the first example, in which `Dynamic` wraps the whole function:

```
{{Hold[$CellContext`x$$], 0}, 
       Dynamic[$CellContext`customControl$$[#, $CellContext`y$$] & ]}
```

This is from the non-working example (no `Dynamic`):

```
{{Hold[$CellContext`x$$], 0}, $CellContext`customControl$$[#] & }
```

The working one suggests another way to get `Manipulate` to work:

```
{{x, 0}, Dynamic[customControl[#1] &]}
```

And indeed it does, though for some reason I don't like it.

The way I usually localize functions like `customControl` is completely within `Manipulate`, like this:

```
Manipulate[
 {x, 1, other},
 {{x, 0}, customControl[#] &},
 {{y, 0}, ControlType -> None},
 {other, 0, 1},
 {{customControl, customControl}, ControlType -> None},
 Initialization :> (customControl[Dynamic[x_]] := True;)]
```

This keeps everything inside a single `DynamicModule`.  (An alternative is to forego `Manipulate` and construct one's own user-interface using `DynamicModule`.)  Note the declaration:

```
{{customControl, customControl}, ControlType -> None},
```

The `{customControl, customControl}` initializes the symbol `customControl` to its undefined self.  Omit it and it will be initialized to `0`, and then the function definition in the `Initialization` code will fail.  One could/should put `Clear[customControl]` in the initialization code instead (but that is not allowed on the Demonstrations site, hence my roundabout, kludgy habit).